# How to access value from a list from an object type using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a service method which will return me an object type.

```
var serviceResponse = InvokeServiceMethod(parameters);
```

I am able to access data from it using reflection for ex:

```
serviceResponse.GetType().GetProperty("NumberOfRecords").GetValue(serviceResponse, null)
```

In the response I have a list but I am unable to access the values. Its throwing error **'Index was outside the bounds of the array'**. I am able to see the data inside. Following is what I am trying to do.

```
PropertyInfo summary= serviceResponse.GetType().GetProperty("SummaryList");
PropertyInfo test = summary.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperty("Name");
```

Comment: What is type of SummaryList property? It seem's to be not generic collection and exception is thrown when empty array from GetGenericArguments is indexed

Comment: I think you may be misusing `GetGenericArguments`, which is only for [generic function type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx).

Comment: So if I don't know which type 'SummaryList' is how can I access the values in it?

Comment: If you want to enumerate collection you can resort to dynamic typing.                                                             `dynamic collection=serviceResponse.SummaryList;foreach(var i in collection) Console.WriteLine(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dima for your suggestion. It worked.. Following is what I did to solve this issue..

```
dynamic collection = serviceResponse.GetType().GetProperty("SummaryList").GetValue(serviceResponse, null);
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    var value = item.Name;
}
```